# "Alternative Login" URL is invalid

Tags: ios, facebook, authentication

I have placed a FB share (formerly "like") button on a page of an iPad app.  When the user clicks on the button he is presented with the FB login screen (assuming he is not already logged in).  Besides entering your username and password, FB offers a "Trouble logging in? Try an alternative login" method on the page.  But if you click on the link, it opens the Safari browser, accepts the username and password, then attempts to process this alternative method of login.  It fails with the error message: "Safari cannot open the page because the address is invalid."

Here is the URL it is trying to process:

[https://www.facebook.com/dialog/permissions.request?_path=permissions.request&app_id=[MY_APP_ID]&redirect_uri=fbconnect%3A%2F%2Fsuccess&sdk=ios&display=touch&type=user_agent&fbconnect=1&perms=read_stream%2Cpublish_stream%2Coffline_access&from_login=1](https://www.facebook.com/dialog/permissions.request?_path=permissions.request&app_id=%3CMY_APP_ID%3E&redirect_uri=fbconnect://success&sdk=ios&display=touch&type=user_agent&fbconnect=1&perms=read_stream,publish_stream,offline_access&from_login=1)

Does anyone know of a solution to prevent this error?  It becomes an undesirable user experience.